# Change Andengine Text By clicking and typing a new text like native android EditText

Tags: android, sprites, andengine, text

I have a board in my game, with a name. I want to edit it on a button click (not by text.setText("text") method ) i want the user to enter a text and set it there. I couldnt find, how to change the changeableText in andengine other than by setText(), Any help is appreciated :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine doesn't have an editable TextBox. You have to do it yourself (programmaticaly of course). Like:

1-Draw a white rectangle (Textbox) and an empty text into it
2-Handle touch
3-Show keyboard
4-Handle Input and [change] / [append to] the text